# How do I load a page and play the sound automatically in a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have created a ViewController, simply named StreamViewController.m where I have this code:

```
    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

and:

```
- (IBAction)play:(id)sender {

        NSString *stream = @"https://soundcloud.com/aviciiofficial/avicii-wake-me-up-extended-mix";

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stream];

        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        [_music loadRequest:request];

    }
```

What I want to do now is to assign some code so that when I click to get into the View Controller, the stream automatically opens up and plays. Right now, it is a lot of annoying steps. First the page loads, and then I have to click on a button to even open the URL (before it only shows a blank/white page) and finally I have to click play. Does anyone know the trick?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) viewDidAppear{
    [super viewDidAppear];
    [self play:nil];
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! That saves me one click at least but it still doesn't play the file automatically. Since you are helping me I can also take the opportunity to ask another question. What do I write so that I can keep listening to the music while running the different sites of the app? As of now, the music dies at the same second that I leave that single view... :/

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't want auto play of Webview .. If I right then use this code .. It will work fine

```
NSString *stream = @"https://soundcloud.com/aviciiofficial/avicii-wake-me-up-extended-mix";

            NSString *embedHTML = @"\
            <html><head>\
            <style type=\"text/css\">\
            body {\
            background-color: transparent;  color: white;  }\
            </style>\
            </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
            <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
            width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
            </body></html>";


        NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, stream, _music.frame.size.width*3, _music.frame.size.height*3];

        [_music loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

Thanks .. :)

Comment: Have u checked this ?

Comment: Hi Joge and thanks for your response! I'm not sure what that should do. Tried to implement it inside the IBAction and nothing really happened. Am I misplacing it? I actually do want to load it automatically but I guess you can't make all wishes come true...

Comment: If you wants automatically play your audio then don't use my code... because my code work for stop automatically play audio in webview